# How to add a blog post programmatically?

Tags: splistitem, blog

I'm trying to create a C# script that will allow me to import blog posts from a different system (exported as CSV) into a SharePoint blog. I have found a script for comments to a blog post, but I'm having trouble finding the write fields/syntax for posts themselves.

```
public static void AddComment(string url)
{
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(url))
    {
        site.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
        {
            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
            SPList commentList = web.Lists["Comments"];
            SPListItem newItem = commentList.AddItem();
            newItem["Body"] = "body";
            newItem["Title"] = "title";
            newItem["PostTitle"] = "2;#post1";
            newItem.Update();
        }
    }
}
```

From the above code for adding comments, I see that it's a simple `SPListItem`. Plus, it appears that the link between comments and posts is the `PostTitle`, but in this example is `2;#post1` pointing to post with ID=2, or does that post have a title of "2" (i.e. would `PostTitle = "My Title;#post 4" work, where my post has the title "My Title" and this particular comment is the 4th one?

Any links/code/advice would be appreciated.

Kevin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2;#post1 is a `SPFieldLookupValue` where the `LookupValue` is "post 4" and the `LookupId` is 2.

The `LookupId` of the item being looked up is the list item ID in the list it's being stored in.

To set the value of a lookup field you have a few options:

```
newItem["PostTitle"] = 2; // Just pass the lookup ID
newItem["PostTitle"] = new SPFieldLookupValue("2;#post1"); // string of lookup field value
newItem["PostTitle"] = new SPFieldLookupValue(2, "post1"); // constructor with ID, value
```

Comment: Thanks - this helps with the comments. Do you have any info on how to add blog posts themselves? This was the focus of the question, though I realize I did talk about comments a lot.

Answer (score 3):

I got it working, with help from rjcup's answer (which help me link them together). here's my working (uncleaned) code:

```
    protected void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string qmSPSiteURL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["qmSPSiteURL"];
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(qmSPSiteURL + "/communityspaces/authoring-zone/blog"))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                DateTime created = DateTime.Now;
                int author = 22;

                SPList postList = web.Lists["Posts"];
                SPListItem newPost = postList.AddItem();
                newPost["Title"] = "New blog added programmatically";
                newPost["Body"] = "This post was added using c-sharp";
                newPost["Created"] = created;
                newPost["Author"] = author;
                newPost[SPBuiltInFieldId.Editor] = author;
                newPost.ModerationInformation.Status = SPModerationStatusType.Approved;
                newPost[SPBuiltInFieldId.PublishedDate] = created;
                newPost.Update();

                int postID = newPost.ID;

                addComment(postID);
            }
        }
    }

    protected void addComment(int postID)
    {
        string qmSPSiteURL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["qmSPSiteURL"];
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(qmSPSiteURL + "/communityspaces/authoring-zone/blog"))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                DateTime created = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-8);
                int author = 72;

                SPList commentList = web.Lists["Comments"];
                SPListItem newComment = commentList.AddItem();
                newComment["Body"] = "This comment was added using c-sharp";
                newComment["Title"] = "New comment added programmatically";
                newComment["PostTitle"] = postID.ToString();
                newComment["Created"] = created.ToString();
                newComment["Author"] = author;
                newComment[SPBuiltInFieldId.Editor] = author;
                newComment.Update();
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps someone :)