# SharePoint Copy Blog to new site collection in c#

Tags: 2013, development, lookup-column

I am trying to make a code that copies Posts and Comments to a site.
It is working, except setting the lookup field to connect Comment with Post.

---

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using System;
namespace SPTools
{
public static class CopyBlog
   {
    public static void CopyItems(string sourceurl, string targeturl)
    {
        SPWeb Sourceweb = new SPSite(sourceurl).OpenWeb();
        SPWeb Targetweb = new SPSite(targeturl).OpenWeb();

        foreach (SPListItem PostItem in Sourceweb.Lists["Posts"].Items)
        {
            // Copy Post
            SPListItem newPostItem = Targetweb.Lists["Posts"].Items.Add();
            newPostItem["Created"] = PostItem["Created"];
            newPostItem["Modified"] = PostItem["Modified"];
            newPostItem["Author"] = PostItem["Author"];
            newPostItem["Editor"] = PostItem["Editor"];
            for (int i = 0; i < PostItem.Fields.Count; i++)
            {
                // Copy all open field values
                if (!newPostItem.Fields[i].ReadOnlyField && newPostItem.Fields[i].InternalName != "Attachments")
                {
                    newPostItem[newPostItem.Fields[i].InternalName] = PostItem[newPostItem.Fields[i].InternalName];
                }
            }
            Console.Write("Updating Post: " + newPostItem.Title);
            newPostItem.Update();
            Console.WriteLine(" - Done");
            Console.WriteLine("Adding Comments: ");
            // Add Comments to the Post


            foreach (SPListItem CommentItem in Sourceweb.Lists["Comments"].Items)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("     Comments Post ID: " + CommentItem["PostID"]);
                if (CommentItem["PostID"].ToString() == PostItem.ID + ";#" + PostItem.ID)
                {
                    SPListItem newCommentItem = Targetweb.Lists["Comments"].Items.Add();
                    newCommentItem["Created"] = CommentItem["Created"];
                    newCommentItem["Modified"] = CommentItem["Modified"];
                    newCommentItem["Author"] = CommentItem["Author"];
                    newCommentItem["Editor"] = CommentItem["Editor"];

                    Console.WriteLine("******** New Value " + newPostItem.ID);
                    newCommentItem["PostID"] = new SPFieldLookupValue(newPostItem.ID, string.Empty);

                    for (int iComment = 0; iComment < CommentItem.Fields.Count; iComment++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(iComment + "\t" + newCommentItem.Fields[iComment].TypeAsString);
                        if (!CommentItem.Fields[iComment].ReadOnlyField && CommentItem.Fields[iComment].InternalName != "Attachments")
                        {
                            newCommentItem[CommentItem.Fields[iComment].InternalName] = CommentItem[CommentItem.Fields[iComment].InternalName];
                        }
                    }
                    newCommentItem.Update();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

> Error: Invalid data has been used to update the list data...

If I remove the line with SPFieldLookupValue, it is working.
Any suggestions to what I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `PostID` you should be updating `PostTitle`

For adding comment you can use below snippet

```
protected void addComment(SPWeb TargetWeb, SPListItem CommentItem, int postID)
{
    SPListItem newCommentItem = Targetweb.Lists["Comments"].Items.Add();
    newCommentItem["Created"] = CommentItem["Created"];
    newCommentItem["Modified"] = CommentItem["Modified"];
    newCommentItem["Author"] = CommentItem["Author"];
    newCommentItem["Editor"] = CommentItem["Editor"];
    newComment["PostTitle"] = postID.ToString();
    newComment.Update();
}
```

[How to add a blog post programmatically?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/56930/how-to-add-a-blog-post-programmatically)

Comment: Great!
I spend 4 hours solving this issue. Why did I only search for lookupfield and not blog... 
Problem solved.

Comment: @CADmageren nice to hear it helped!